# Spring Security: How to use multiple URL patterns in FilterRegistrationBean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a bean

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean animalsFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new AnimalsFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns(
        "/api/cat",
        "/api/cat/**",
        "/api/dog"
    );
    ...
    return registration;
}
```

In that bean, I use two patterns for `/api/cat**` URLs. The problem is that when I try to call endpoints with complex postfix (`/api/cat/1/feed`), my filter does not intercept the request. But it's OK when I call `/api/cat` and `/api/got` endpoints -- filter works as expected and intercepts requests.

How can I use multiple URL patterns for my case (`/api/cat`, `/api/cat/**`)?

*PS*

I have tried to use next pattern combinations:

```
1) /api/cat, /api/cat**, /api/dog
2) /api/cat, /api/cat/**, /api/dog
3) /api/cat**, /api/dog
```

Comment: @goat have you tried just `/api/cat/*`

Comment: The javadoc for `FilterRegistrationBean` will soon be updated to mention the url pattern syntax it accepts is according to the servlet spec, so users don't confuse the pattern with the ant-matcher pattern used by spring security.

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned by @Tarun Lalwani, you need to use `*` instead of `**`, because `**` is not a valid url pattern in this case.

In your case, try the following:

```
    registration.addUrlPatterns(
        "/api/cat",
        "/api/cat/*",
        "/api/dog",
        "/api/dog/*"
    );
```

those would match `/api/cat/1`, `/api/cat/1/feed`, `/api/dog/1`, `/api/dog/1/feed`, ...

If you want to replicate the `/api/*` behavior that would, only match `/api/this` but `/api/not/that`, then you need to use the following pattern: `/api/*/`.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html

> When no URL pattern or servlets are specified the filter will be associated to '/*'

As you can see `*` is the pattern used by `spring` and not `**`. `**` is usually a glob used by `bash`, `golang`. But spring uses `*` only. So what you need is just

```
registration.addUrlPatterns(
        "/api/cat",
        "/api/cat/*",
        "/api/dog",
        "/api/dog/*"
    );
```

The `**` patterns are usually used in the security filters

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/security-filter-chain.html#filter-chain-proxy

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/restful/**" filters="
        securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCFalse,
        basicAuthenticationFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="
        securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue,
        formLoginFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't think `/api/cat` and `/api/dog` will not be caught if you only include `/api/cat/*` and `/api/dog/*` as filters. You probably need to include `/api/cat` and `/api/dog` as well in your url patterns.

Comment: @TwiN, it was already there in OPs question and that is why to show more on patterns I had removed it. But its updated now to include both

Comment: @TwiN & Tarun You were right - I had incorrectly assumed the patterns were supposed to be Ant matcher style patterns like used in spring security url patterns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is: the filter is being called on every endpoint call, ignoring the patterns i've set:

`myBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/cat/*","/dog/*","/serpent/*"));`

i've created the bean inside @SpringBootApplication class.

so if i call http://server/api/animal/elephant the filter is being hit, and i don't think this is the expected behaviour since i've set the url patterns