# Spring Security Filter not honering URL patterns

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-filter

I've set up some security filters in my Spring Boot application and I have defined specific URL patterns I want

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomAuthenticationFilter> authenticationFilter(){

  FilterRegistrationBean<CustomAuthenticationFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

  registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter());
  registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/data/*", "/record/*","/records/*","/storage/*","/query/*");

  return registrationBean;
}
```

I'm adding the filter into the WebConfig like so

```java
 @Override
  public final void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf()   .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
        .antMatcher(ApplicationInfoService.API_PATH + "/info")
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
```

When I make a request to something like the following;

`http://localhost:8080/api/record/v1/record/search?offset=0&count=0`

the filter isn't activated. However, I did notice the url in the antMatcher did activiate the filter, so maybe there's something there.

Either way, I'm still trying to grasp how much of the api path the `addUrlPattern` needs? Where or what else do I need to add beside adding `addFilter<Before|After>` in the WebSecurityConfig class.

I have taken a look at a whole lot of examples and questions in SO, but none seem to have helped me. Hoping someone can help me understand what else I could be missing.

Comment: *"have defined specific URL parameters I want"* Where? I see an `addUrlPatterns` call, but no `addUrlParam` call, probably because there is no such method on [`FilterRegistrationBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html).

Comment: *"any endpoint with that matches the urlParam list"* Like what? Give us an example of something that doesn't work, but you believe should work.

Comment: *"beside adding `addFilter<Before|After>`"* Well, you're *not* adding an `addFilter<Before|After>` anywhere, so are we looking at the same code you are?

Comment: I put `param` instead of `pattern` and have fixed the typo. I've also added some more clarification into the question as well as adding where I'm doing `addFilter` which specifically is `addAfterFilter`.

Comment: @chrylis for the `addUrlPattern`? I was looking at this [SO Question/Answer (very similar to mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769047/spring-security-how-to-use-multiple-url-patterns-in-filterregistrationbean) and the suggestion is ** not a valid url pattern? I'm new to spring boot and such, so I'm definitely missing something there.

Comment: @chrylis `FilterRegistrationBean` is for registering servlet container filters, so the pattern must be a servlet/filter mapping pattern like `/path/*` or `*.ext`.

Comment: The first code snippet will add a ServletContainer-level filter. The second code snippet will add a SpringSecurity-level filter. Given the name of your filter class, I highly doubt the first is what you want, so remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc of [`.antMatcher(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-) says

> Allows configuring the `HttpSecurity` to **only be invoked when matching the provided ant pattern**.

This means that your security is only ever applied to `/info` requests. All others bypass security.

The code you wrote is the same as:

```
http.antMatcher(ApplicationInfoService.API_PATH + "/info");
http.addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
http.csrf()
      .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
http.authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Note that the following are two entirely different things:

```
http.antMatcher("/foo/**");

http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/foo").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
```

Without the first, security processes all requests. With it, only requests with path `/foo` are processed by the security module, while all other requests entirely bypasses security.

The second specifies that requests with path `/foo` are permitted, and that all other requests requires a user with role `ADMIN`.